# Is "total boundedness" a topological property?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have been trying to find a counterexample of ...

If $d$ and $e$ are topologically equivalent metrics (they generate the same open sets), and $(X,d)$ is totally bounded then $(X,e)$ is totally bounded.

Any ideas?

Comment: try to come up with a compatible totally bounded metric on the reals, something like $\dfrac{|x-y|}{1+|x|+|y|}$ (I did not verify that this particular formula defines a metric, but it is something along these lines).

Comment: Notions of boundedness in general are not topological properties. Nearness isn't truly characterized in topological spaces; open sets kind of tell you about nearness, but not in the sense of boundedness. For instance, the metric $d(x,y) = \min\{|x-y|,1\}$ generates the same topology on $\Bbb R$ as the usual topology but that metric is bounded, whereas the usual metric is not bounded.

Answer (score 1):

If $d(x,y)$ is a metric, then $\frac{d(x,y)}{1+d(x,y)}$ is another metric giving the same topology but bounded by 1.

(I'll leave it to you to show A. It's a metric, and B. They give the same topology.)

---

As I was asleep and missed that *totally bounded* is what you asked about:

Not every metric space has a topologically equivalent metric that's totally bounded, but any subset of e.g. $\mathbb{R}$ does, by a homeomorphism from $\mathbb{R}$ to $(0,1)$, for example $f(t) = \frac{1}{1+e^{-t}}$ gives a homeomorphism $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow (0,1)$.

The example another poster gave, that $\{1/n : n \in \mathbb{Z}, n > 0\}$ has the discrete topology but is totally bounded, is a simple example of this phenomenon.

Comment: There is a different between bounded and totally bounded.

Comment: For example, if $d$ is the discrete metric, that new metric is also discrete and is not totally bounded if the space is infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $\mathbb N$. Let $d$ be the discrete metric and $e:\mathbb N\times\mathbb N\to[0,\infty)$ defined as $$e(n,m)\equiv\left|\frac 1n-\frac 1m\right|\quad\forall n,m\in\mathbb N.$$
Then $e$ is a totally bounded metric, whereas $d$ is not totally bounded. However, both $d$ and $e$ induce the discrete topology.